# SAML2.0 Authentication(Based on IDPSSODescriptor)

Tags: saml

I need to authenticate a SAML Respone , The Identity Provider has provided a metadata file. What are the steps to verify the SAML Response against contents of metadata ?.

Answer (score 1):

One common answer, based around most federated SAML systems, is that you need to use the public key from the metadata to verify the signed response. If  verifying a signature with a public key is an unfamiliar concept, spend a little time reading around PKI or "public key infrastructure." Then you should move to the [XML Signature Specification.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/)

I note that CAS uses SAML2 but does not build its trust infrastructure on signatures but on whitelists of service providers who are allowed to present tokens.

If you are using the PKI trust model, the signature should be in the `<ds:Signature>` element.  The metadata should contain the public key in  the `<KeyDescriptor>` element, ideally with the attribute use = signing. See  Section "5 SAML and XML Signature Syntax and Processing" of [the SAML Core specification](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf) for more details.

Other security checks include:

- Is there a "InResponseTo" attribute? From Core: "...it MUST be present and its value MUST match the value of the corresponding request's ID
  attribute."
- Is there a "Destination" attribute? From Core: "If it is present, the actual recipient MUST check that the URI reference identifies the location at which the message was received. If it does not, the response MUST be discarded. "

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was based on a PKI trust model , I got the certificate from the metadata file , the SAML Response was checked against the certificate in the metadata file.